# Querying DashBoard Data

Tags: salesforce-id, custom-object, standard-objects

I'd like to query the data of dashboard particularly the stored '**ID**'. Is it possible to get the stored dashboard data **ID** through SOQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the `Dashboard` object to get the dashboard's ID, and the `DashboardComponent` elements for that dashboard. Take a look at the [SOAP API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/).

Comment: FolderId - Returns the ID of the Folder that contains the dashboard. Is this is the only id object?

Comment: `Dashboard.Id` is the ID of the dashboard, `Dashboard.FolderId` is the ID of the folder the dashboard resides in, and `Dashboard.RunningUserId` is the running user for the dashboard. That's about it. Not sure what you're looking to access...

Comment: I can find the Dashboard Id and Running UserId but could you guide me where i can find the rsid(Dashboard chart id)?

Comment: There's no way to get "rsid"; it's on a table that isn't supported in SOQL (internal use only). You can only use the metadata API to get or set the configuration.